# Integration over ellipse

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

> $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\mid \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac {y^2}{b^2}=1\}$. Find $\int_A (\cos x)y\,dx+(x+\sin x)\,dy$.

Can someone please please give a methodological answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Notice $y\cos(x) dy + (x+\sin(x))dy = xdy + d(\sin(x)y)$. Since $A$ is a closed loop and the second term is an exact differential, it contributes nothing when you integrate it over $A$. The rest is simply the formula of area enclosed by $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you parametrize your ellipse : $A = (a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \rvert \theta \in [0,2\pi[$. So you have :
$$\left \lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
x = a\cos\theta\\
y = b\sin\theta
\end{array}
 \right. \Rightarrow \left \lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
dx = -a\sin\theta \, d\theta\\
dy = b\cos\theta \, d\theta
\end{array}
 \right. $$
Then rewrite your integral as :
$$\oint_A y\cos x \, dx + (x + \sin x)\,dy = \oint_A x\,dy + d\left(\sin(x)y \right)$$
The last term vanishes because one integrates an exact differential on a closed loop.
To compute the first term one uses the paremetrization of $A$ :
$$\oint_A x\,dy = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} ab \sin^2\theta \, d\theta = \pi ab$$